# Invalid CSRF Token was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

Tags: spring, wildfly

I'm running a Spring/Angular 4 project and locally everything is working fine in Wildfly. But when I run the project on a Linux server using the same Wildfly version and I log in from the Angular 4 framework to the API I get a reponse saying:

> Invalid CSRF Token '8c385082-2ce3-4e18-8f86-65820df02***' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Anyone else ever had something like this?

Comment: Sometimes I get that, I don't know why